# Does tradingview use ask/bid price when backtesting

Tags: pine-script

It seems an obvious question, but I have not found any infomation on web. When backtesting strategies using tradingview, does it use bid/ask prices when place short/long orders?

If not, how should I set the commission correctly if I am trading Forex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TradingView historical bars contain no tick data and use only OHLC information:
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Strategies.html

For commission settings, see here and the equivalent settings in the script's *Settings/Properties* dialog box:
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask if its correct to set the commission if forexample EURUSD has spread 1.3 pip, then I choose commission type as `cash_per_order` and set the value to 1.3 ?

Comment: If you want to account for the spread, would probably be better to just enter 13 ticks of slippage. This parameter can also be specified both in the script's `strategy()` declaration statement and in the *Settings/Properties* dialog box where you can play with the value while the *Strategy Tester/List of Trades* tab is active. You will be able to confirm its impact on fills immediately.